# Coverage.py only detects calls during import, not during test execution

Tags: python, pytest, code-coverage, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I cannot get `coverage.py` to correctly measure code coverage for my Python package. Whatever I try I only get coverage for the code run during import, i.e. `package/__init__.py` and code called from there, and 0% coverage for all the code called during the execution of the tests. The package is installed as an editable install with `pip install -e .` inside a Docker container.

If I strip the project down to create a minimum example, the issue disappears, which shows that the it must be caused by something specific in the actual project, but unfortunately I cannot share the actual code (work-related).

I have run out of ideas of what to try (see attempted fixes below). What could be the problem?

#### General project structure

```
/app/
  setup.py
  package/
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    ...
  tests/
    __init__.py
    conftest.py
    test1.py
    ...
```

#### Version information

- Python: 3.7.2 inside a Docker container based on `python:3.7-slim`
- pytest: 6.0.1
- pytest-cov: 2.10.0
- coverage: 5.2.1

#### Things I have tried

- Checking the path to the code run in my tests through `inspect.getsourcefile(func)` to ensure the correct source file is used and not an installed copy somewhere else
- Running the test/coverage commands either through the `pytest-cov` plugin or directly with `coverage run --source package -m pytest tests/ && coverage report`
- Running from different directories, e.g. `/app/`, `/app/tests/` and `/`
- Setting `PYTHONPATH="."`
- Moving the `package` directory into a separate `src` directory [as recommended in the Pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/goodpractices.html)
- Removing imports in `conftest.py` to avoid importing before coverage analysis starts
- Importing package code inside tests instead of at the test module level
- Downgrading `coverage.py` to an earlier version

Comment: how do you run pytest-cov?

Comment: @momo With `pytest --cov package tests/` (or similar, depending on which directory I run from).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a typo, but  there is an equals sign missing `--cov=package`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have actually tried both and they seem to be equivalent. Both `--cov package` and `--cov=package` lists all the files in the package that I want to test, but with 0% coverage.

Comment: Does pytest discover your tests? Are they executed?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: All tests are discovered, and run just fine. I will try to create a minimal example and rewrite it into something I can share. However, as I wrote, I have already tried to copy the project and strip it down to a minimum which did not work. Getting to a minimal example by "divide and conquer" will be time-consuming, but I will try to find that time as soon as I can.